# Find a row having maximum occurrences of 1

Tags: algorithm

I came across this question in an interview.
You have a nxn matrix containing 1s and 0s. You have to find the a row containing maximum number of 1s in most efficient way. I know it can be done in n^2 but is there any optimum solution for this ?

Comment: You can't beat Omega(n^2) worst case, because the worst case is that there's only one 1 in the entire matrix, hence the problem reduces to finding it and you have to check them all. Most obvious optimization I can think is that if the best-so-far is `m`, and the number of 1s you have found so far in the row you're checking is `k`, and there are fewer than `m-k` remaining columns to check, then bail out early since your current row clearly doesn't beat the best so far. There may also be stuff you can do with SIMD instructions, and parallelizing to take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: better than n^2 implies that you don't visit all cells in the matrix. There can be situations where the max row can be determined quickly but for the general case you must visit all cells at least once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The optimal solution is O(n^2). Assume that the matrix contains only zeros. You have to inspect every cell to be sure of this. This is O(n^2).

You could optimize the algorithm so that it stops searching if it finds a row that contains only 1s (this must be optimal) or if it has seen so many zeros in a row that it could not possibly beat the maximum seen so far. This could give a significant speed-up in some cases, but it would still be O(n^2) in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

As an optimization: you parse the columns, calculate the MAX of 1 per row since now. After n/2 steps u start to eliminate those rows not suitable. `(The rows with MAX number of 1s - rowSum(number of ones in that row) > (the number of columns unchecked)` - complexity `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

Worst case complexity will anyways be O( n<sup>2</sup> ).

But we can reduce the constant and general complexity.

Calculate #1's in x `(x < n)` number of rows.

For remaining n-x rows, stop as and when we find that we are not in position to find bext answer from that row.

Now the point is to obtain optimal value of x.

PS: Analogous to - Select the best man out of 100, given the condition that you can choose only thrice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "most" efficient implementation in JavaScript.

Like the above answers suggest; it short circuits if you hit a row with N 1's and continues the outer (row) loop if there is no possibility of the current row having a greater amount of 1's.

But this answer also demonstrates efficiently using (read: placing) the conditional logic involved.

```
// return the smallest row index 0 - (N-1) containing the greatest number of 1's
function MaxRow(M, N) {
// initialize max to 0 if you want to return null for an all zero matrix
// initialize max to -1 if you want to return 0 (row 0) for an all zero matrix
var max = 0;
var result = null;
var row1s;
rowLoop: 
for(var row = 0; row < N; row++) {
    row1s = 0;
    for(var col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        if((N - col) + row1s < max) { // row's current potential 1's
            continue rowLoop; // next row
        }
        row1s += M[row * N + col]; // + 0 or + 1
    }
    if(row1s > max) { // new max
        max = row1s; // save new max value
        if(max == N) { // largest possible
            return row;
        }
        result = row;
    }
}
return result;
}
```